How can i recover access to my desktop environment if i lost user login password in this POST message Ubuntu?
This POST message Ubuntu is Ubuntu from the latest Ubuntu version realeased before 5 years have passed and the login password i am talking about is the login password for login in my Ubuntu desktop environment

Can you get into recovery mode?

Your details I find somewhat confusing; latest Ubuntu version before 5 years means you're running what?  You can overwrite your hashed/password with a known hashed like any OS (including windows etc), or for some releases also non-destructively re-install so you can set a password (this method seems overkill; but I've used it myself in this way for some reason). Your tagging desktop-environments confuses me as I don't see how you think they relate; DE & WMs mostly user standard user accounts, is your system non-standard?  Do note: I've assumed no-encryption here is involved !!

also note:  I didn't understand your reference to Power On Self Test message, besides those messages are firmware specific so we cannot help unless we have clear details of your hardware and thus what POST checks/messages are possible (and happen to know what hardware), however this isn't a firmware/hardware site; and I can't see how POST relates to an installed OS (outside of a brief issue over ~3 days with Ubuntu 17.10 back in 2017-October)

how can i find out my pc hardware specifications without formatting my PC drives  if my PC is using the latest Ubuntu release compatible with a 4 MB RAM PC?

You can boot a PC using live media; eg. use Ubuntu install media but select the "Try Ubuntu" option, and the session will run from RAM (code from thumb-drive or install media) and nothing will be installed. 4MB?? so this is a machine for 1994? (machines upgraded to 1GB back in ~1999-2002).  Its best if you're specific and avoid terms like latest, just edit the question and clearly say what you're using, eg. Ubuntu 4.10 Desktop, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Server, Ubuntu Core 24 etc, and be precise with details.

This question is similar to: how to reset a lost admin password?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
